# Android: animation for layout visiblity gone

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation

I am trying to show an animation when **layout visiblity Gone** like naviagtion drawer.

When the user swipe left to right "**Layout visible**" and when swipe right to left "**Layout visiblity Gone**".I want an animation like navigation drawer closing when the layout visiblity Gone;

I tryed..

```
  android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

**Main Activiy.java**

```
v.animate().translationX(0).alpha(0.0f).setDuration(100000);
```

Also I tryed

**anim_left_to_right.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="1500"/>
```

**anim_right_to_left.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="1500" />
```

**Main Activity.java**

```
 layout_left.setVisibility(View.GONE);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_right_to_left,R.anim.anim_left_to_right);
```

Can any one please help me to show animation while layout visiblity Gone

Answer (score 1):

Put this property in xml

```
 android:fillAfter="true"
```

Comment: you mean only need this propery, no other animation needed @Ashish Patil

Comment: this  code for activity to activity transition overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_right_to_left,R.anim.anim_left_to_right)

Comment: if u put  android:fillAfter="true"  this property then it will stay on his lat anim position after animation

Comment: so which animation should i use for layout visiblity gone @Ashish Patil

Comment: Use this code for reference ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
      Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.myanimation);
      image.startAnimation(animation);